# How to have a ScrollView to start at the bottom, and scroll over Google Map component?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I have the following code:

```
 <MapView
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            google={this.props.google}
            style={{
              width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
              height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
              zIndex: -1,
            }}
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: this.state.centerLat,
              longitude: this.state.centerLng,
              latitudeDelta: 1,
              longitudeDelta: 1,
            }}
            zoomControl={false}
            mapTypeControl={false}
            streetViewControl={false}
            fullscreenControl={false}
            gestureHandling="greedy"
            onPress={() => this.onMapClicked()}
          >
          </MapView>

        <ScrollView
          styleName="card-menu"
          style={{ alignSelf: "center", position: "absolute" }}
          contentContainerStyle={{ alignSelf: "center", justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'flex-end' }}
          onScroll={(event) => this.businessScroll(event)}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
          style={{ zIndex: 999, position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 150 }}

        >
          {this.state.businessMerchants.map((merchant, index) => (
            <Business
              merchant={merchant}
              key={merchant.id}
              isCurrentItem={index === this.state.currentItemIndex}
            />
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
```

What I want is for the  to start near the bottom (maybe 100 or 200 pixels from the bottom) of the map, on top of it, and upon scrolling, I want each of the items inside the ScrollView to scroll up over more and more of the map.

Is there a way to do that? I'm able to put the ScrollView over the map with position: "absolute" and pointerEvent: "box-none", but then I can't access the map beneath it.

How do I access both of these and also have scrolling over the map view?